# Ubuntu doesn't boot and shows blank screen or check signal cable, what is wrong?

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu is not booting, at first it showed a blank screen with mouse pointer, and currently it shows check signal cable. What could be wrong ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that, if you're on a desktop, you've probably fried your video output.

The good news is, if that's the case, all of your data should be completely fine. 
The bad news it that you'll have to buy a new video output/adapter for your computer.